# Как выровнять текст под картинку?

Tags: html, css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
        <div class="last-text text-center">
            <h4>
            Вы можете оставить заявку 5 удобными спосабами для вас 
            </h4>
        </div>

    <div class="pisati">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 text-center">

        <p class="pisati-vk">
            Вконтакт 
        </p>
        <div class="vkk-img">
                        <img src=https://pp.userapi.com/c841136/v841136657/71c7e/nqEn6hJlWnI.jpg alt="tel+vr">
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 text-center">

        <p class="pisati-vk">
            Вконтакт 
        </p>
        <div class="vkk-img">
                        <img src=https://pp.userapi.com/c841136/v841136657/71c7e/nqEn6hJlWnI.jpg alt="tel+vr">
    </div>
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">

        <p class="pisati-vk">
            Вконтакт 
        </p>
        <div class="vkk-img">
                        <img src=https://pp.userapi.com/c841136/v841136657/71c7e/nqEn6hJlWnI.jpg alt="tel+vr">
    </div>
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">

        <p class="pisati-vk">
            Вконтакт 
        </p>
        <div class="vkk-img">
                        <img src=https://pp.userapi.com/c841136/v841136657/71c7e/nqEn6hJlWnI.jpg alt="tel+vr">
    </div>
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">

        <p class="pisati-vk">
            Вконтакт 
        </p>
        <div class="vkk-img">
                        <img src=https://pp.userapi.com/c841136/v841136657/71c7e/nqEn6hJlWnI.jpg alt="tel+vr">
    </div>
    </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">

        <p class="pisati-vk">
            Вконтакт 
        </p>
        <div class="vkk-img">
                        <img src=https://pp.userapi.com/c841136/v841136657/71c7e/nqEn6hJlWnI.jpg alt="tel+vr">
    </div>
    </div>
```

Надо чтобы текст стоял красиво на картинке Заранее спасибо

Comment: https://codepen.io/mustafich/pen/jZMWgx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.vkk-img {
  position: relative;
}

.vkk-img img {
  width: 100%;
}

.vkk-img p {
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.pisati-vk {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="last-text text-center">
    <h4>
      Вы можете оставить заявку 5 удобными спосабами для вас
    </h4>
  </div>

  <div class="pisati">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <div class="vkk-img">
          <p class="pisati-vk">
            Вконтакт
          </p>
          <img src=https://pp.userapi.com/c841136/v841136657/71c7e/nqEn6hJlWnI.jpg alt="tel+vr">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <div class="vkk-img">
          <p class="pisati-vk">
            Вконтакт
          </p>
          <img src=https://pp.userapi.com/c841136/v841136657/71c7e/nqEn6hJlWnI.jpg alt="tel+vr">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <div class="vkk-img">
          <p class="pisati-vk">
            Вконтакт
          </p>
          <img src=https://pp.userapi.com/c841136/v841136657/71c7e/nqEn6hJlWnI.jpg alt="tel+vr">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <div class="vkk-img">
          <p class="pisati-vk">
            Вконтакт
          </p>
          <img src=https://pp.userapi.com/c841136/v841136657/71c7e/nqEn6hJlWnI.jpg alt="tel+vr">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <div class="vkk-img">
          <p class="pisati-vk">
            Вконтакт
          </p>
          <img src=https://pp.userapi.com/c841136/v841136657/71c7e/nqEn6hJlWnI.jpg alt="tel+vr">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 text-center">
        <div class="vkk-img">
          <p class="pisati-vk">
            Вконтакт
          </p>
          <img src=https://pp.userapi.com/c841136/v841136657/71c7e/nqEn6hJlWnI.jpg alt="tel+vr">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```